# async/await method throws exception -type int is not a subtype of bool

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling a graphql endpoint which returns success, but I do get an exception on the calling method.

Here is my calling method -

```
await AmplifyInstance()// this is where I get the exception. Snip below
     .createUserOnAzureCosmosDB(user)
        .then((result) {
            print(result['data']['userPhoneNumber']);
              _intlPhoneFieldController.text =
                    (result['data']['userPhoneNumber'].toString())
                                .substring(1);
                     _incrementStep('continueOnProfilePictureWidget');
});
```

Here is the called method -

```
Future<dynamic> createUserOnAzureCosmosDB(User user) async {
    HttpLink link = GlobalVariables().graphqlEndpoint;
    GraphQLClient graphQlClient = GraphQLClient(
      link: link,
      cache: GraphQLCache(
        store: InMemoryStore(),
      ),
    );
    try {
      QueryResult mutationResult = await graphQlClient.mutate(
        //Mutation query here
      if (mutationResult.data?['createUser'] != null) {
        print('Created user on Cosmos DB');
        registerUserStatus['result'] = true;
        registerUserStatus['data'] = mutationResult.data?['createUser'];
      }
    } on ApiException catch (e) {
      print('Mutation failed: $e');
      registerUserStatus['result'] = false;
      registerUserStatus['errorMessage'] = e.message;
    }

    return registerUserStatus;
  }
```

And the returned registerUserStatus is just an array -

```
var registerUserStatus = {};
```

Here is the exception -
[image]

UPDATE eamirho3ein
Here is the result of print("result=$result);

```
I/flutter (14224): result = {result: true, data: {__typename: User, partitionKey: user, userPhoneNumber: 14160000000, userDisplayName: testuser, avatarUrl: www.url.com, createdAt: Today}}
```

Comment: could you please `print("result = $result");` inside `then` method and show us the result?

Comment: error saying int isnt a subtype of double

Comment: Your error will probably get ridiculously easy to debug, once you stop making it hard on yourself combining `then` with `await`. There is no point in using `then` here, other than making it hard to find the error. Use `await`.

Comment: Also, what is `registerUserStatus`, why isn't that a local variable? And why is the Future having a `dynamic`, not the actual type? You are only returning that one variable ever, so set the type.

Comment: @eamirho3ein I have the result of result to the post

Comment: @nvoigt would be able to prettify the code. Just want to see what you meant.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "prettify". It's not about looking pretty. You don't even know which line your error occurs on, because you chained this `then` call. Drop it. Use the result of the `await` and continue normally. Then at least, you will get a proper line number for your error, instead of "somewhere in this chain".

Comment: So `await AmplifyInstance().createUserOnAzureCosmosDB(user).then((result) {` should become `final result = await AmplifyInstance().createUserOnAzureCosmosDB(user);`

Comment: @nvoigt  I see no errors now. Thanks. Please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually an *answer*, but rather a way to find the answer more easily yourself:

`then` chains make it increasingly hard to find your problem, because the compiler/debugger/IDE has a harder time pointing you to it. So don't do it.

With `async`/`await` available from the beginning, there never has been a reason to use `then` in any Dart program.

```
await AmplifyInstance().createUserOnAzureCosmosDB(user).then((result) {
```

Is equivalent to just writing:

```
final result = await AmplifyInstance().createUserOnAzureCosmosDB(user);
```

And then continuing on with the code you had put in the lambda function in the `then` part. Obviously, you need to remove the closing bracket somewhere too now.

This way, your error will actually pop up where it happens, not at the `await` of a huge chain that leaves you wondering what the problem might be.